# Restrict Metadata for Custom Content-Type in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack, metadata, content-type

Have a few custom content-types registered via

```
ContentTypeFilters.Register(contentType, StreamSerializer, StreamDeserializer);
```

and would like to restrict the display for routes on the metadata page. These content-types are only meant to be used with request dto's which are restricted to `InternalNetworkAccess`. Just looking to not clutter up the public facing metadata page with stuff that isn't necessary.

For the builtin contentTypes you would just add it under the `RestrictAttribute`. Is there a similar feature hidden somewhere else that isn't documented yet maybe for the custom types?

It looks like **perhaps** I could customize the `MetadataFeature` plugin and possibly restrict which request dto's get the content type and which don't. But I only just recently noticed that, and not sure how well that would turn out (also don't really know yet how to remove the MetadataFeature and safely replace with my own).

Essentially I only want this custom contentType visible on the metadata page for the requestDtos restricted to InternalNetworkAccess.
Any ideas?

Edit:
Also am still on ServiceStack v3, but still interested in possibilities for v4.

Comment: So you can't use `[Restrict(AccessTo = RequestAttributes.Localhost, VisibilityTo = RequestAttributes.Localhost)]`on the methods that use the custom contentType?

Comment: The Dto's are already restricted. So when I hit my page over public address I only see the "External" Dtos, and when I hit it over the private network I see "External" + "InternalNetworkAccess" Dtos on the metadata page. When you register a custom content-type that appears on EVERY metadata page apparently. I really only need the custom content-types to appear for the InternalNetworkAccess Dtos. Like if I were to turn off the SOAP feature in ServiceStack, none of the SOAP content stuff appears in the metadata page. I want to do the same but for custom type.

Comment: Are you using v3 or v4?

Comment: v3. Is it capable in v4?

Comment: I have tested in v4, and it definitely works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found that the initial class handling the metadata requests was `ServiceStack.MetadataFeature` an `IPlugin`. This actually controls both the layout of the underlying example request/response page (for each content-type) as well as the overall "/metadata" page.

From this small segment

```
private IHttpHandler GetHandlerForPathParts(String[] pathParts)
{
    var pathController = string.Intern(pathParts[0].ToLower());
    if (pathParts.Length == 1)
    {
        if (pathController == "metadata")
            return new IndexMetadataHandler();

        return null;
    }
    ...
}
```

is where the handler for the actual "/metadata" page is sent off. You don't find the actual construction of the ContentTypes per request until you get down a little further, inside `IndexMetadataHandler`'s parent class `BaseSoapMetadataHandler` in the method

```
protected override void RenderOperations(HtmlTextWriter writer, IHttpRequest httpReq, ServiceMetadata metadata)
```

An internal control is created (`IndexOperationsControl`) which has a method `RenderRow`, which is where all the magic occurs. Here you'll see some obvious checks for the "Operation" (which is another word for the Dto now) and ContentType like

```
if (this.MetadataConfig.IsVisible(this.HttpRequest, EndpointAttributesExtensions.ToFormat(config.Format), operation))
```

So all that needs to be done is create your own class of `IndexOperationsControl` and handle the config.Format in the RenderRow method. The config.Format is simply everything after the forward slash in the ContentType you registered, so if it was "application/x-my-type" the config.Format String will be "x-my-type". Operation is simply the class name of the RequestDto. Unfortunately because the class is marked internal it means you pretty much have to copy it completely instead of using inheritance. In order to keep a 1:1 likeness with how the pages are generated by default you'll also need a copy of the internal classes `ListTemplate`, `TableTemplate`, and `XsdTypes` (used in construction of `IndexOperationsControl`).

After this you simply need your own `IndexMetadataHandler` and overload `RenderOperations` (you can use inheritance for this one) to create your new `IndexOperationsControl`. Also we'll need our own `MetadataFeature` equivalent IPlugin but we'll need to copy it completely and modify `GetHandlerForPathParts` to return our new `IndexMetadataHandler`. The only other thing to do is remove MetadataFeature and add our own as a plugin.

```
    // removing default metadata feature
    Plugins.RemoveAll(x => x is MetadataFeature);
    // add our custom one
    Plugins.Add(new CustomMetadataFeature());
```

Voila, you can display custom ContentTypes exactly how you want per RequestDto.

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent your custom type from showing up in the metadata using.

If your content type is `application/yourformat` you would use:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    IgnoreFormatsInMetadata = new HashSet<string>{ "yourformat" }
});
```

Comment: This would partially solve the problem, but then it would ignore them completely. Think I'm going to try playing with the MetadataFeature plugin where it generates GetHandlerForPathParts. Seems like I should be able to have it ignore the content-type at certain points there.

Comment: Also it is possible in v3 as well.

Comment: @Nicholi Cool, I didn't know that. Can you point me to the documentation or source code that shows v3 ignoring format?

Comment: I actually just noticed it hunting through EndpointHostConfig. It's called under the same property name too, IgnoreFormatsInMetadata. 

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/EndpointHostConfig.cs

Comment: I found you actually can customize the Metadata page a bit more without recompiling all of ServiceStack (yay), in a way that allows you to choose which custom ContentTypes appear for which RequestDTOs. Gonna add it as an answer sometime tomorrow. Only require a tad bit of copying some internal classes from ServiceStack.

Comment: @Nicholi Good call. I never noticed that.